# Python Logging functions

Tags: python, oop, logging

```
logger = logging.getLogger('application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

class blah()

    def blah1(self)
        ....
        ....
        self.logger.DEBUG("You dont have root privileges")

    def blah1(self)
        ....
        ....
        self.logger.DEBUG("You dont have root privileges2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b= blah()
    b.blah1()
```

Guys im trying to get each of my functions to report into a log file in my python script. But its not logging. Where have i gone wrong?

Thanks
William

Comment: self.logger.DEBUG("You dont have root privileges") , can you please show the line where you have defined logger in class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the simplified answer

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

class blah:
    def blah1(self):
        logger.debug("You dont have root privileges")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b= blah()
    b.blah1()
```

NOTE: debug should be small case, and please used global logger. as you are initializing it in global scope

Answer (score 1):

try

```
class blah():
    logger = logger

    def blah1(self)
        ....
        ....
        self.logger.DEBUG("You dont have root privileges")

    def blah1(self)
        ....
        ....
        self.logger.DEBUG("You dont have root privileges2")
```